# What are AGF Files, how do we put them in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, well-known-text

I came across term which says AGF, after Googling I found its Autodesk Geo Files, But some other say, Atlas Geo Files, Which one of them is right. I also came to know that It is an extension to WKT format supported by PostGIS.

Is there a way where we could make POSTGIS consume the AGF Files.

Comment: With this kind of ambiguity, it would be helpful to see the first few lines (if text, i.e., open in Notepad or whatever), or a hexdump of the top few bytes. In the end, it will be a challenge as both potential formats do not have OGR drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AGF files (Atlas Geo Files) are Atlas GIS native binary geodataset files. These store information about the spatial data. 
You can find these lines in AGF files. They are usually a set of 2 files with `.AGF` and `.AIF`  extentions.

```
ATLAS*GIS
Copyright (C) 1996
ESRI Inc.
```

We can open these files via ARCVIEW sofware form ESRI INC.

There are tools like shpagf.exe and agfshp.exe which will convert from shape to agf and agf to shape respectively.
you can find those download links here.
http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/samples-and-utilities/view/productid/25/metaid/513

And using these shape files we can load the data into PostGIS with PostGIS shape file loader or shp2pgsql.exe