# How to approximate "Autodesk Geometry Format" string to GeoJson

Tags: python, geojson, autodesk

I'm having a problem reading following geometry format:

```
CURVEPOLYGON ((x1 y1 (LINESTRINGSEGMENT (x2 y2, x3 y3, x4 y4, x5 y5), CIRCULARARCSEGMENT (x6 y6, x1 y1))))
```

...from what I searched this should be [AGF Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Variations) format used by [Autodesk](http://download.osgeo.org/fdo/3.4.0/docs/FDG_FDODevGuide.pdf).

My goal is to convert such geometry into GeoJSON (preferably in python3). Since GeoJSON doesn't support curves then approximation is the way to go. Approximation WKT to GeoJSON [can be solved](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256123).

Does anyone know how to convert such structure into WKT or directly to GeoJSON?

Comment: Maybe the tools from this answer can help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26888/what-are-agf-files-how-do-we-put-them-in-postgis They should enable AGF -> SHP and then with fiona you can do SHP -> GeoJSON

Comment: I have seen that Q&A already, @Kersten, but I'm dealing with Autodesk-GF, not Atlas-GF. Thanks for the comment though, updated the question title.